# Apple Approval for Keychain

Tags: iphone, keychain

After update on my iPhone 7, I was prompted to set up some sort of approval where I needed to approve my phone from another device. When I went to my second device it asked to verify from another device also. I go to my third and last device to approve both the iPhone and the iPad from my MacBook and it says my MacBook needs to be approved too!? How am i supposed to approve all my devices if they all need approved?

Comment: To which version of iOS did you update your iPhone 7? Can you make a screenshot or provide the exact contents of the approval message and add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has many security features within their iCloud Keychain. According to **[this support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085)**, you do have some options:

- You can use your iCloud security code that you set up when you started using iCloud Keychain. If you enter it too many times incorrectly, you will have to **[contact Apple support](https://support.apple.com/contact)** to try again. Too many incorrect tries will delete your security code from Apple's servers.
- You can also verify your identity with a text message sent to the number used when first setting up iCloud Keychain. If you no longer have access to this number, you can also **[contact Apple support](https://support.apple.com/contact)** for more help.

Hope you can get this sorted out!

Comment: Any chance you would edit this to point to an official Apple KB or link to support? It's a good start and could be a great answer with a little extra detail.